# Is it possible to tell what machines I'm logged in to (but disconnected from)?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, scripting, automation

I infrequently work on about 20 Windows servers via remote desktop. There are times when it'd be really convenient to know if and where I have disconnected sessions open.

Is there a powershell script or query or something I can use to make this process simpler than logging into each machine and checking Task Manager's users tab?

Comment: Note: I already use mRemote--it's not connecting that's a hassle--it just seems like there ought to be a way I can script this

Answer (score 0):

Terminal manager lets you connect from one window to multiple servers and show the various sessions and their status (and processes running, etc.) as well as connect to them to resume sessions.

Comment: Can it tell me which machines might have disconnected sessions?

Comment: Terminal manager does list the state as active or disconnected.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: Should be with Windows Server systems. Are you only running home/pro versions of Windows?